# How get tag value using DOM parser

Tags: java, dom, xml-parsing, domparser

I use dom parser in my app. So. i have next situation:

XML:

```
<test>
    <A>
      <B>hello</B>
    world
    </A>
</test>
```

Code:

```
private TagA parseTagA(Node node) {
        TagA tagA = new TagA();
        if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
            NodeList childList = node.getChildNodes();
            for (int i = 0; i < childList.getLength(); i++) {
                // gets child
                Node child = childList.item(i);
                // parse <B> tag
                if (child != null && "B".equals(child.getNodeName())) {
                   tagA.setTagB(parseTagB(child));
                }
            }
        }

        String tagABody = node.getTextContent();
        tagA.setBody(tagABody);


        return tagA;
    }
```

I use node.getTextContent() method to get value of tag A, but i get value of tag B too. I mean what value of "tagABody" is"hello world", but should be just "world". Method getNodeValue() return null, i guess because node type is ELEMENT_NODE. Anyway i have question:How i can get value only of tag A, only "world" ? Thanks.

Comment: Your A node has two children, a B Node and a text node. you could test the type of node in the loop or usually the nodename of a textnode is #text

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test it, but I believe the below code should work:

```
private TagA parseTagA(Node node) {
    TagA tagA = new TagA();
 String tagABody  = "";
    if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
        NodeList childList = node.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < childList.getLength(); i++) {
            // gets child
            Node child = childList.item(i);
        if(child.getNodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
           tagABody = node.getNodeValue();
           tagA.setBody(tagABody);
            } else
            // parse <B> tag
            if (child != null && "B".equals(child.getNodeName())) {
               tagA.setTagB(parseTagB(child));
            }
        }
    }


    return tagA;
}
```

Comment: It is highly appreciated if you mark the answer as accepted if it resolves your problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest processing the text node children of the `A` element.

You can do this in the loop of child nodes that you are doing anyway.  The `if` that identifies tag `B` for you would have an `else`, in which you would accumulate the non-`B` text.